# iOS orientation for phonegap app

Tags: ios, xcode, jquery-mobile, cordova, orientation

I'm working on an iPhone app built jQuery mobile and phonegap (1.4.1). I've limited the app orientation to portrait, however for a photo gallery and video playback I would like to allow landscape orientation.

Is there a way I can achieve this? I assume I would need to allow for both orientations, then possibly run a check against the content before allowing a change?

Wondering whether I could use:

```
stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString
```

with:

```
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
```

to call a javascript function to return the current page, and if either the gallery, or video playback, allow orientation to change to landscape? But have been unsuccessful so far.

Any help would be much appreciated.